# Eclipse clearcase plugin is slow when compiling snapshot view due to excessive network access

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I'm using Rational Clearcase SCM adapter in RSA/RAD 8, and is using snapshot view.

I have just found out that a full rebuild of our code takes
15 seconds when the clearcase plugin is "disconnected.", but
when connected it takes more than 90 seconds - on a good day...

Since the CPU, disk, and also the network is more or less 
idle while compiling, I used wireshark to trace what's going on.

The delay seems to be caused by excessive network traffic, a
few packages going forth and back to the clear case server for 
each file touched in the snapshot view. Note; it's not a dynamic view.

Is there a way to stop clearcase or the plugin from accessing the server? 
It can't be important, it works perfectly fine in "disconnected" mode.

Comment: Odd, the very nature of a snapshot view is that they dont communicate unless you call an operation. Is your workspace configured correctly? i.e. are you seeing this on every CC view you create?

Comment: Yes it's consistent. There are supposedly some hidden plugin options that may help, but the view to configure plugin options crashes since it seems to contain 1.000.000 rows or so in RSA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deactivated the Clear Case SCM adapter, and installed the Clear Case Remote Client instead.

The time to do a "rebuild all" time was reduced from 100s to 20s.

Answer (score 1):

What usually slows down everything is, for the [ClearCase Eclipse plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213), is the activation of some options which involve a constant lookup of the view:

[image: ClearCase plugin option]

(from [this developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0406_manji/0406_manji.html))

For instance, "perform refresh status recursively" is suspect.
Also, "When checked in files are edited by an internal, non-interactive editor => Automatically check out" doesn't help if, for some reason, you have resources checked in which must be modified by each compilation.

So try to deactivate as many options as you can in order to isolate the one which might cause the issue.

Comment: I've toggled all options - no difference. I found a reference to some options in the view 'Plug-In Registry', but IBM has included so many plugins in RSA that the view spins eclipse to death, if i try to open it...