# Eclipse: How to disable check-out option if file has compilation errors

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

How to disable eclipse clearcase check-out option if a file has compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Check from the [ClearCase Eclipse plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674) options the ones which says "Automatically checkout".
(see "[Eclipse ClearCase plugin is slow when compiling snapshot view due to excessive network access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921362/6309)" for illustration)

By deactivating all of those options, you might avoid the automatic checkout on compilation error.

This is assuming you are not using the old [Sourceforge Eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/).